# How do I beat gold rank strike team missions?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

My strike team members fail a lot, even on bronze.  Their success chance on gold rank missions are way way low (15% or less), but those are the only missions I have left.

How do I complete them with my strike team?

Comment: What level are your strike teams, 15+ character level would be required, if you were to play it yourself

Comment: they're level 12 and 10 at the moment

Comment: They are not high enough to take on hold.  Do Silver missions

Comment: @Ramhound the only missions available to me right now are gold ones.

Comment: Then; continue to do them, even if your team fails they level

Comment: failing missions gains negative traits sometimes, which lowers success chances. IMHO you are better off waiting for missions to expire and new ones to appear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your team doesn't have enough effectiveness, then they simply don't have enough effectiveness. They'll need to level up more, by completing more strike missions. To avoid gaining negative traits, you shouldn't send them on missions they have little to no chance of finishing successfully.

If the only ones you have left are ones they can't do, then it's best to just wait for new ones.

I have a level 9 team that usually has about a 60% chance to complete silver missions, but essentially no chance to complete gold missions.

According to the [Gamepedia wiki](http://masseffectandromeda.gamepedia.com/Strike_team),

> Once you've maxed a squad's level, equipment is how you will give them the additional boost to succeed on Gold Tier Strike Missions. Even at the max level of 20, squads have an average success rating on gold tier missions of only 50-55%. Equipment is just like your weapons, or abilities. Once purchased, they provide a permanent boost to your squad's effectiveness. They retain the equipment from mission to mission, pass or fail.

So, in order to consistently beat gold missions with strike teams, you'll have to max their level and give them lots of equipment.

Comment: what level would they have to be to start being able to have a decent shot (~70%) success rate?

Comment: @lI On gold? I don't know. My guys aren't there yet. I think the highest is maybe level 9. He has over 50% to do silvers, but can't do golds yet. Bronze is around 90%. Failures have only resulted in one negative trait so far.

Comment: @lI Found some more info. At max level they still have only an even chance without equipment.

Comment: thanks, so with traits and gear I can boost it up to 70% perhaps